# Issue validating xml signature generated by xml-crypto node module

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, saml-2.0, xml-signature

I am implementing a SAML 2.0 node.js identity provider.  As a proof of concept I wanted to show that the service was available to a .net consumer or service provider.  I am using the [node-samlp](https://github.com/auth0/node-samlp) library.  The problem that I am having is the xml SAMLResponse is signed by the npm package, and I am trying to validate the xml Signature using a .net web application.  The validation fails...

Here is the javascript which I have written to serve the identity provider piece:

```
function postSuccess(req,res,next,userId){
    return ms.call('ms.ip.claims.getClaims').then(function(claims){
      return samlp.auth({
        cert: fs.readFileSync('c:\\temp\\test.pem').toString(),
        key: fs.readFileSync('c:\\temp\\test.key').toString(),
        signatureAlgorithm: 'rsa-sha1',
        digestAlgorithm:'sha1',
        getPostURL: function(wtrealm,wreply,req,callback){
          callback(null,req.samlRequest.AssertionConsumerServiceURL);
        },
        profileMapper: profileMapper,
        issuer: '<my-company>'
      })(req,res,next);
    });
}
```

This generates the SAMLResponse and posts it back to my .net web application successfully, but I'm running into problems as I try to validate the signature of the xml file.

Here is the validation code on the .net side:

```
            public bool IsValid(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
            {
                var cert = new X509Certificate2();
                cert.Import("c:\\temp\\test.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
                var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                manager.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
                var nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ds:Signature", manager);
                var signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
                signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NWithCommentsTransformUrl;
                signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);
                return signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true);
            }
```

The pem and key used on the node side are generated from the pfx cert used on the .net end of things.  I'm not getting any error messages, just a false result for `signedXml.CheckSignature(cert,true)`.

Any words of advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe turning on digital signature tracing would give you some clues? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80310179-00bd-4af3-8928-288b325d8269/signedxml-checksignature-enable-signedxmldebuglog?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: @explunit Thanks i'll look into that.

Comment: Are you sure you're not modifying your signed xml with the statement signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = signedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NWithCommentsTransformUrl; This line should not be necessary and could break the signature.

Comment: @sk_ It is possible, but I added that after much failure.  The code you're seeing here is after 2 days of tweaking things trying to get the validation to pass.

Answer (score 1):

For verifying the signature you do not need to supply a password and load the private key from .pfx. This means you can eliminate any potential issues with wrong public key by simply loading the same .pem as used on the node-samlp side.

I took your sample code and changed these lines:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import("c:\\temp\\test.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
```

To this:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\temp\samlp.test-cert.pem");
```

(that file is [provided with the test harness](https://github.com/auth0/node-samlp/blob/master/test/fixture/samlp.test-cert.pem) of node-samlp).

And it worked fine using the below sample node Idp (also mostly stolen from the test harness of node-samlp):

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var samlp = require('samlp');

var fakeUser = {
  id: '12345678',
  displayName: 'John Foo',
  name: { familyName: 'Foo', givenName: 'John' },
  emails: [ { type: 'work', value: 'jfoo@gmail.com' } ]
};

var options = {
  issuer:     'http://myidp',
  cert:       fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'samlp.test-cert.pem')),
  key:        fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'samlp.test-cert.key')),
  signatureAlgorithm: 'rsa-sha1',
  digestAlgorithm:'sha1',
  RelayState: 'test',
  getPostURL: function (wtrealm, wreply, req, cb) { 
    return cb( null, 'http://localhost:2181/AuthServices/Acs')
  },
  getUserFromRequest: function(req){ 
    return fakeUser 
  }
};

app.get('/samlp', samlp.auth(options));

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Warning for anybody else reading later: the .Net code in the question is just a proof of concept. In real life you need a lot more than this to verify a SAML assertion and protect against e.g. [XML Signature Wrapping attacks](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final91.pdf). Using established .Net SAMLP component such as [KentorIT.AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) or a commercial product is more advisable. *Disclosure: I'm a contributor to AuthServices (but not an owner).*